# Regex search and replace with optional plural

Tags: regex, replace, preg-replace

I'm a novice at regex, so hopefully some expert can just yawn at my question with an easy answer. I'm trying to find and replace words that start with a certain letter and keep them plural if they are plural.

So, for example, I want to replace replace the word "boy" with "band", and "boys" with "bands"

```
text.replace( /\b(b)[\w]+(s?)\b/gi, "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">$1and$2<\/span>" );
```

However, $2 isn't coming up with the optional "s".

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply change `[\w]+` to `[\w]+?`.

This changes

**from "greedy"** (match as many characters as possible and only give characters up if forced to)
which means `s?` will not match because `[\w]+` already did it for us. (wrong behavior)

**to "lazy"** (match as few characters as possible, only adding to the match if absolutely necessary)
which gives `s?` an opportunity to match. (correct behavior)

By the way: You can change `[\w]+?` to `\w+?` and it will work exactly the same.

Comment: Perfect! I figured the \w was grabbing it, but I didn't know about this option! Thanks!

Comment: This solution falls a little short on some plurals. _kiss_ to _kisses_, _lady_ to _ladies_ are two examples. Less obvious examples are also _leaf_ to _leaves_, _life_ to _lives_. You could extend the regular expression above with an or condition, e.g. `^\b[\w]+(s|i?es|ves)\b$` it falls short a little on `kiss` which matches, but most other cases it appears to match reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

`[\w]+` has already matched the "s". The solution is to make `[\w]+` match as few as possible, instead of as many as possible, with the "?" modifier. Thus:

```
\b(b)[\w]+?(s?)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the pattern like `/\b(([A-Za-z]{3,})+(s))\b/`

```
$text="boys";
echo preg_replace('/\b(([A-Za-z]{3,})+(s))\b/','$2',$text); //output "boy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the PHP question [Regex - How to search for singular or plural version of word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405660/regex-how-to-search-for-singular-or-plural-version-of-word)

If you know what your search term is, it can be pretty simple. Here's a simple example I use in PHP to highlight all occurrences of a search term whether it is singular, simple plural (s), all lowercased or first letter uppercased:

```
function add_highlight($content,$term)
{
    //always remove last s if it exists
    //and could use similar strategy to test other endings such as -es and -ies
    //by conditionally building the regex test string based on term's ending
    $term_no_s = rtrim($term,"s"); 
    return preg_replace("/({$term_no_s}s)|({$term_no_s})/i", "<span class='highlight'>$0</span>", $content);
}
```