# Regex - How to search for singular or plural version of word

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm trying to do what should be a simple Regular Expression, where all I want to do is match the singular portion of a word whether or not it has an s on the end. So if I have the following words

```
test
tests
```

EDIT: Further examples, I need to this to be possible for many words not just those two

```
movie
movies
page
pages
time
times
```

For all of them I need to get the word without the s on the end but I can't find a regular expression that will always grab the first bit without the s on the end and work for both cases.

I've tried the following:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)([s\b]{0,}) - This returns the full word as the first match in both cases
([a-zA-Z]+?)([s\b]{0,}) - This returns 3 different matching groups for both words
([a-zA-Z]+)([s]?) - This returns the full word as the first match in both cases
([a-zA-Z]+)(s\b) - This works for tests but doesn't match test at all
([a-zA-Z]+)(s\b)? - This returns the full word as the first match in both cases
```

I've been using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for trying out the different regex's.

EDIT: This is for a sublime text snippet, which for those that don't know a snippet in sublime text is a shortcut so that I can type say the name of my database and hit "run snippet" and it will turn it into something like:

```
$movies= $this->ci->db->get_where("movies", "");
if ($movies->num_rows()) {
    foreach ($movies->result() AS $movie) {

    }
}
```

All I need is to turn "movies" into "movie" and auto inserts it into the foreach loop.

Which means I can't just do a find and replace on the text and I only need to take 60 - 70 words into account (it's only running against my own tables, not every word in the english language).

Thanks!
- Tim

Comment: You want a specific word to be matched, or an arbitrary word?  Also, it's not always *s*, sometimes it's *es*.

Comment: English plural form, even excluding the irregular ones, are not as simple as removing `s` at the end. What would you do for cases such as "tomatoes" or "parties" or "leaves" (leaf)?

Comment: Yep I realize that, in this case I only have a few words that this regex will be used against and all have / don't have s on the end.

Comment: Can we just concentrate on the question please, rather than exceptions. It's for a sublime text snippet and the regex will only be run against my table names. Some don't need the s removed as they don't have it on the end but a lot do.

Comment: Probably better to rethink whether a regex is the right approach. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: @jahroy - As I mentioned in the comment this is for a sublime text snippet, it's not used in my code thus I have to use a regex for it and I can't just do a find and replace.

Comment: @Tim - changed my answer below... However you've given us very little info about your context.  Command line linux? Sed? Vi? Will the word be the only word on the line? Are you trying to search replace?  Are you just looking for the singular portion of plural words?  You need to give us some info....

Comment: I'm disappointed that people would downvote this question when it could help out users in the future who need to search for a string with a certain modifier or letter on the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution:

```
([a-zA-Z]+?)(s\b|\b)
```

Works as desired, then you can simply use the first match as the unpluralized version of the word.

Thanks @Jahroy for helping me find it. I added this as answer for future surfers who just want a solution but please check out Jahroy's comment for more in depth information.

Comment: Quick googlers beware: of course, this is **not a solution to the problem in the title** in general, so please don't just copy-paste it and call it a day. ;) (It only solved a special subcase Tim needed 8 years ago for some internally used script of his. Just telling, 'coz Google dropped me here, too, and it took me some time to figure out what's going on with the "obviously wrong" regex here.)

Answer (score 9):

For simple plurals, use this:

```
test(?=s| |$)
```

For more complex plurals, you're in trouble using regex. For example, this regex

```
part(y|i)(?=es | )
```

will return "party" or "parti", but what you do with that I'm not sure

Comment: Can you write that in a way so it works for many words, not just "test" and "tests" please.

Comment: @Tim Can you try to do a little bit of work yourself please?  How hard would it be to just loop over your words and add the endings described here to turn them into regex?

Comment: Just search for an expression that ends in `s` if you're just searching database tables... But what if the table name ends in `S` and is singular?

Comment: Frankly, I'd search for both as literals not using regex

Comment: The first only matched "test" if tested with "tests", but did not match anything when tested with just "test"

Comment: @dom I added an alternate following term for end-of-input that will allow "test" to match

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it with vi or sed:

```
s/\([A-Za-z]\)[sS]$/\1
```

That replaces a bunch of letters that end with S with everything but the last letter.

NOTE:

> The escape chars (backslashes before the parens) might be different in different contexts.

ALSO:

> The `\1` (which means *the first pattern*) may also vary depending on context.

ALSO:

> This will only work if your *word* is the only word on the line.

If your table name is one of many words on the line, you could probably replace the `$` (which stands for *the end of the line*) with a wildcard that represents whitespace or a word boundary (these differ based on context).

Comment: Thanks! I had a look through your edits and found the last edit helped a lot (explaining doing an or with whitespace). I solved it with the following regex: ([a-zA-Z]+?)(s\b|\b) (and then I just grab the first group)

Comment: Cool.  I missed the `sublimetext` tag, so I was wondering if I should have not even bothered.  All of the above constructs might be slightly different in `sublimetext`, but my answer should get you headed in the right direction.  (feel free to upvote)

Comment: I didn't add that because I thought I could leave it generic as it really is simply a regular expression question that could be applied to many different use cases. Unfortunately many users discussed the context instead of actually helping find a solution.

Comment: I think context makes a huge difference even for general regex questions... For example, the syntax can vary quite a bit.